# Define a generic method like current_user rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to create a generic method like the `current_user` method provided by Devise which is usable on views and controllers. In my case, I want to know the current company.

My code :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

before_action :set_company

protected

  def set_company
    @current_company =|| nil
    if current_user.admin? && session[:company_id].present?
      @current_company =|| Company.find(session[:company_id])
    else
      @current_company =|| current_user.company
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've got almost does it... just add the method itself and make it a helper method so it's available in views.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  helper_method :current_company

  before_action :set_company

  def current_company
    @current_company
  end

protected

  def set_company
    @current_company =|| nil
    if current_user.admin? && session[:company_id].present?
      @current_company =|| Company.find(session[:company_id])
    else
      @current_company =|| current_user.company
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

add the helper_method property, 
and make the method public

```
helper_method :set_company
```

this will make it available in every view in your application